# Changing a store state value from a component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a table that contains objects defined in the store. In the component where i display the table, i can click on the table rows to gain more information about the contents of this specific row. What i want to do is, when i select a row, to be able to change a value in the state from false to true in order to populate another table with the contents of just the selected row. Here's some code:

store.js

```js
const state = {
selectedLimitCard: {},
limitCards: [
{ limitCardSelectedStatus: false }
]}

const mutations = {
  selectLimitCard: state => {
    state.limitCards.forEach(limitCard => {
      if (limitCard.limitCardSelectedStatus == true) {
        state.selectedLimitCard = limitCard;
      }
    });
  }
};

const actions = {
  selectLimitCard: ({ commit }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(
          "!Store! value: " + state.limitCards[0].limitCardSelectedStatus
        );
        commit("selectLimitCard", state.selectedLimitCard);
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
};

const getters = {
  getLimitCards: state => {
    return state.limitCards;
  },
  getSelectedLimitCard: state => {
    return state.selectedLimitCard;
  }
};
```

component.vue

```js
       <v-btn
          id="nextStep"
          color="#009af9"
          large
          dark
          @click="
          modifySelectedLimitCardStatus(),
          selectLimitCard"
        >Select</v-btn>

  data: () => ({
    editedLimitCard: {
      limitCardSelectedStatus: ""
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getLimitCards"]),
    ...mapActions(["selectLimitCard"])
  },

  methods: {
    modifySelectedLimitCardStatus() {
      this.editedLimitCard.limitCardSelectedStatus = true;
      this.$store.state.limitCardSelectedStatus = this.editedLimitCard.limitCardSelectedStatus;
      console.log(
        "This is the edited item: " +
          this.editedLimitCard.limitCardSelectedStatus +
          "\nThis is the store value: " +
          this.$store.state.limitCardSelectedStatus
      );
    }
  }
```

So far, when i'm logging the values in the component, everything is fine, but the value in the store's state remains unchanged. I'm trying to change the values in the component because that's where i have acess to the logic which row is selected. Can someone point me in the right direction what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your action triggered? Try to prevent changing the Vuex state directly...

Comment: @SimonThiel Yes, the action is triggered on the button click iliustrated above.

Comment: `commit("selectLimitCard", state.selectedLimitCard);` the second parameter is not used by the mutation `selectLimitCard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `modifySelectedLimitCardStatus()`, the Vuex state is being modified directly:

```
this.$store.state.limitCardSelectedStatus = this.editedLimitCard.limitCardSelectedStatus;
```

According to https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html:

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, i have to figure out a way to determine which item is currently selected, and then run a mutation directly in the store to modify the state?
It can't be done in the component?

Comment: Only special functions, known as "mutations" are allowed to modify any values saved inside the Vuex state.
The mutation methods, are defined inside Vuex. They are called from components by using `commit`.
If you try to modify Vuex state data in any other way, other than a mutation, it will not work.